# What's the maximum number of bluetooth connections on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, bluetooth, ipod

If you have any insight on this, it would also be nice to know whether there's a big latency between connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bluetooth protocol specifies that connections are point-to-point (hence the term "pairing"), but different profiles can be used concurrently with different stations. Each profile only supports one connection at a time. You can have a stereo headset connection with your car and a data connection with your laptop at the same time, but not multiple data connections.

Correction: you are correct that I was incorrect. Quoting [from this link](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/bluetooth1/):

> Bluetooth-enabled devices are
>   organized in groups called piconets. A
>   piconet consists of a master and up to
>   seven active slaves

Comment: So basically Data is a Bluetooth profile and only one connection is allowed for that at a time right?

Comment: Hum, just found this that suggests it is possible to connect multiple iPhones using the game kit: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html