# How many other devices can a single bluetooth device can connect to?

Tags: java, networking, bluetooth, connection, bluecove

I mean with how many devices can it communicate simultaneously or one by one without terminating an active connection?

Specifically i would say with the bluecove implementation

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963614/android-bluetooth-chat-sample-app-multiple-connections and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958416/whats-the-maximum-number-of-bluetooth-connections-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Using google i found https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/bluecove-users/iPRwEDGZ2pM

The answer has already been posted on Stack by dennis mathews at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309835/1214163